# Cannot execute macros for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Try to execute macros for the table with multiple sheets. First sheet has Names (column A) and individual numbers of participants (column B). That's the list of the participants of the events. The rest of the sheets are info from events -- indvidual numbers of the participants (column A) and their names (column B). What I need to do is to check for people from the first sheet on all the other sheets and display the results in the first sheet (column C) -- if the person was present, and if so, on which sheeet (or sheets) they can be found. Tried to ask ChatGPT but the code doesn't work...

[image]

[image]

```
Sub CheckDa()

    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsEvents As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowMain As Long
    Dim lastRowEvents As Long
    Dim participantRange As Range
    Dim eventRange As Range
    Dim participantCell As Range
    Dim eventCell As Range
    Dim participant As String
    Dim presentSheets As String

  
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRowMain = wsMain.Cells(wsMain.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each wsEvents In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If wsEvents.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            lastRowEvents = wsEvents.Cells(wsEvents.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
End Sub
```

Well, I've tried everything. Simple formulas seem not to work for this amount of data

Comment: Your code is invalid and therefore cannot run. You get an error message from the compiler complaining about a missing `End If` - and if you fix that, it would complain about a missing `Next`. Use "Debug-Compile VBA project" and fix all errors, else it can't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting,  try code below. I would use functions to make code more readable and maintainable.

```
Sub CheckDa()

    Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsEvent As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowMain As Long, lastRowEvent As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim participantNumber As String, presentEvents As String
    
    InitializeMainWorksheet wsMain, lastRowMain
    
    For Each wsEvent In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If IsEventWorksheet(wsEvent) Then
            lastRowEvent = GetLastRowForColumn(wsEvent, "A")
            UpdatePresentEvents wsMain, wsEvent, lastRowMain, lastRowEvent
        End If
    Next wsEvent

End Sub

Sub InitializeMainWorksheet(ByRef wsMain As Worksheet, ByRef lastRowMain As Long)
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRowMain = GetLastRowForColumn(wsMain, "B")
End Sub

Function IsEventWorksheet(ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    IsEventWorksheet = ws.Name <> "Sheet1"
End Function

Function GetLastRowForColumn(ws As Worksheet, col As String) As Long
    GetLastRowForColumn = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Sub UpdatePresentEvents(wsMain As Worksheet, wsEvent As Worksheet, lastRowMain As Long, lastRowEvent As Long)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim participantNumber As String, presentEvents As String, eventCell As Range
    
    For i = 2 To lastRowMain
        participantNumber = wsMain.Cells(i, 2).Value
        presentEvents = wsMain.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        For Each eventCell In wsEvent.Range("A2:A" & lastRowEvent)
            If eventCell.Value = participantNumber Then
                presentEvents = AppendEventName(presentEvents, wsEvent.Name)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next eventCell
        
        wsMain.Cells(i, 3).Value = presentEvents
    Next i
    
End Sub

Function AppendEventName(existingNames As String, newEventName As String) As String
    If existingNames = "" Then
        AppendEventName = newEventName
    Else
        AppendEventName = existingNames & ", " & newEventName
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked the first time! You are magician at keyboard, Sir!

Comment: Great, Don't forget marked it “accepted”